# Why we should use the setUp and tearDown in testing and not only the test method directly?

Tags: java

Assume I have the following simple code:

```
public class SimpleOperations {
    public int square(int x){
        return x*x; 
    }
}
```

Now to test the previous method, the following works perfectly:

```
public class Jtest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        SimpleOperations test = new SimpleOperations(); 
        int output = test.square(5); 
        assertEquals(25, output);       
    }
}
```

Why would we need adding the setUp and tearDown methods? Running the code just like that shows whether the methods are correct or not. What advantage would the setUp/tearDown methods add to the test? And how they should be like here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need to add setUp and tearDown methods but it is common to do so to follow the "Don't repeat yourself (DRY)" principle of software development.

Some people like to avoid using setUp and tearDown methods to keep tests isolated, so that no extra variables or objects that may have been initialised by the setup interfere with the current test.

As for your basic example, I don't see any advantage in adding setUp and tearDown methods.

Answer (score 1):

CAUTION: This is a slightly long answer. I'll try to keep it as concise as possible.

For a simple example like the one you've shown, there is no need for any setup or tear down for your tests.

However, consider the situation where you are testing a complex service with a bunch of dependencies, you will want to use setup method to... well... set up the objects you need for your test. This would include mocking your dependencies such that calling the methods of your service will not fail. Failure test cases would then only alter the mocks to test out a failure case.

A tear down would help to clear artifacts that your tests created so that the next test can work without having to get interfered by what was left over from previous tests. Think of clearing the records in the test (in-memory) database that were added as part of running your test or by the test case itself.